# How to proceed forward with my data with python for process parameters?

Tags: python, math, statistics, correlation, pca

I am working on an injection molding machine to analyze process data for some parameters to determine what parameters are related or if they are, which ones are important to determine a change in the condition of the machine.

I have plotted the correlation matrix heatmap for the parameters, from which  I can see some positive and negative correlation between different parameters. I have attached a picture [Heat Map for selected parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmrWa.jpg). The problem I am facing now is some parameters may be or may not be related theoretically and also some of the related data (from the figure) have completely different units.

I want to do further analysis of this data. Please suggest a path about what should I be doing now. Should I proceed towards PCA or regression analysis or something else?

PS: I wanted to share my data regarding the same but I don't know how or where to upload it.

Thank you in advance